# Sql Query to insert data based on id

Tags: mysql

I currently have 4 tables,

**Guardian**
-Name
-RankingG

**Times**
-Name
-RankingT

**Identity**
-idName
-Name

**Ranking**
-idName
-RankingT
-RankingG

**Times** and **Guardian** do have some different names. I have currently inserted the Names from **Times** and **Guardian** into Identity with an autoincrement idName. Now how do I insert the RankingT into **Ranking** from **Times** with the corresponding idName from **Identity** and do the same with RankingG from **Guardian**

Comment: Sounds like an insert trigger, SPROC, and/or [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) to me

Answer (score 0):

Note: This will not work if there are duplicate Name's:

```
INSERT Ranking (idName, RankingT)
SELECT i.idName, t.RankingT, g.RankingG
FROM `Identity` i 
    LEFT JOIN Times t USING(Name)
    LEFT JOIN Guardian g USING(Name)
```

Comment: Hi, this really help with one table of data, what if there were 2. I have update the q

Comment: @user405516 Ok, i updated my answer. But next time you have a problem, try to figure it out by yourself. you see how easy it was, simply adding another `JOIN`. read up the various tutorials available on the internet. I am not trying to tell you off, but you are not going to get anywhere if you do not learn by yourself.